# I can't see Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I installed Android Studio and followed all of instructions and I've installed its Emulator also, but When I tried to test a simple "Hello World" code I didn't see the Emulator's option after "Initializing ADB" and it was a blank page !

[image: Screenshot]

**So what can I do to make it work perfectly?!**

Answer (score 1):

An Android emulator is an **Android Virtual Device (AVD)** that represents a specific Android device. You can use an Android emulator as a target platform to run and test your Android applications on your PC.

follow below links:

1. https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html
2. https://www.embarcadero.com/starthere/xe5/mobdevsetup/android/en/creating_an_android_emulator.html
3. http://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/create-avd-virtual-device-emulator-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable virtualization technology in your bios first for emulator to work
Then navigate to your hidden files look for your android folder search for haxm program and install this will enable you to have an emulator

lastly in your android studio select an android virtual device of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You see a blank page is because that page is used for emulating your app to a real devices. To do this, connect you real devices (with ADB Debugging enabled) to your computer, and check it again.

[image: My devices]

If you want a virtual android device emulator, click the "Create New Virtual Device".

Answer (score 0):

I also face to the same problem or error.It was about render problem. The solution is that:

Go to ==> build.gradle(Module: app) ==> dependencies ==> change from

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'` to

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'`

maybe your code does not beta01 but you must know that if your code different from alpha1 changed it

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Wipe the data of your Android virtual Device and then start the emulator. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. The Flutter app was running on the Android Emulator, but I was not able to see it.

The solution was to select for the Graphics property of the Android device, the option: "*Hardware - GLES 2.0*", and then to press the "*Finish*" button.

[image]